# What are the programming languages for GPU

Tags: programming-languages, gpu

I read an article stating that GPU are the future of supercomputing. I would like to know what are the programming languages used for programming on GPU's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCL is the open and cross platform solution and runs on both GPUs and CPUs.
Another is CUDA which is built by NVIDIA for their GPUs.

HLSL,Cg are few others

Answer (score 2):

CUDA has quite a few language ports.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA