# Random Forest interpretation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using [scikit-learn's Random Forest Regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) to fit a random forest regressor on a dataset. Is it possible to interpret the output in a format where I can then implement the model fit without using scikit-learn or even Python?

The solution would need to be implemented in a microcontroller or maybe even an [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array). I am doing analysis and learning in Python but want to implement on a uC or FPGA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out graphviz, which uses 'dot language' for storing models (which is quite human-readable if you'd want to build some custom interpreter, shouldn't be hard). There is an `export_graphviz` function in scikit-learn. You can load and process the model in C++ through boost library `read_graphviz` method or some of other custom interpreters available.

Comment: it looks like `export_graphviz` is in `sklearn.tree` and takes as a parameter, a decision tree.  How would one apply this to an ensemble method such as `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`?

Comment: @Los Random forest is merely a set of trees and hence can be exported in graphviz.

Comment: Cool. I just noticed the estimators_ field for getting the individual regressors: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html .  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could trying extracting rules from the tree ensemble model and implement the rules in hardware.

You can use [TE2Rules](https://github.com/linkedin/TE2Rules) (Tree Ensembles to Rules) to extract human understandable rules to explain a scikit tree ensemble (like GradientBoostingClassifier). It provides levers to control interpretability, fidelity and run time budget to extract useful explanations. Rules extracted by TE2Rules are guaranteed to closely approximate the tree ensemble, by considering the joint interactions of multiple trees in the ensemble.

References:

TE2Rules: You can find the code: https://github.com/linkedin/TE2Rules and documentation: https://te2rules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ here.

Disclosure: I'm one of the core developers of TE2Rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by this part:

Now, that I have the results, is it possible to interpret this in some format where I can then implement the fit without using sklearn or even python?

Implement the fitting process for a given dataset? tree topology? choice of parameters?

As to *'implement... without using sklearn or python'*, did you mean 'port the bytecode or binary' or 'clean-code a totally new implementation'?

Assuming you meant the latter, I'd suggest [GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057548/what-are-the-programming-languages-for-gpu) rather than FPGA or uC.

Answer (score 0):

For a microcontroller implementation, it is usually most practical to use C. There are a few libraries that support converting a scikit-learn RandomForestRegressor to C code, including:

- [micromlgen](https://github.com/eloquentarduino/micromlgen)
- [m2cgen](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen)
- [emlearn](https://github.com/emlearn/emlearn)